C# - Desktop application - Restrict App self access to file explorer
I'm actually in a research phase for a personnal projet i'm thinking of and i have a question about a topic for which i can't seem to find an appropriate answer on the net.

Context :

A Desktop application in .NET (called here : the main app)
"The main app" is used to create smaller other applications (called here : the product)
"The product" is intended to be distributed to public users for usage (let say : everyone on the internet)
"The product" Can be modded (add plugins.. etc) during it's creation process, using "The main app"
mods / plugins can be made by any user


Issues :
In regard of security i'm wondering if it's possible to limit "The product" access to the user's file system. As i want to prevent people to create harmfull plugins/mods.
My first lead was using virtualisation or container but it seem a little bit too much and heavy and with unecessary depencies.
My last lead would be to play with the application permission itself (by default it have the user default permission but i'm wondering if it can be restricted) as mods/plugins will not be directly executed, but will be executed within "The product" instead.
I'm struggling a little bit to find a working theory, and so i'm wondering if you can help me find others idea or leads ? :)

I don't have code to share as this is only theories in my mind for now. I don't even have an architecture as this will be chosen depending on how i can resolve issues in my concept.
I plan to use .NET by default as it's my preferred language.
